# Always show scrollbar for ListView

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar

There are ListViews in some activities of my app.

Since Android 2.1 or 2.2 scrollbars will be only displayed if the user scroll the list or for very short time at the beginning. Then scrollbars will disappear.

Is it possible somehow to show them always as for example in Android 1.5?

Answer (score 110):

In your xml set `android:fadeScrollbars="false"`

Comment: At least here the "fadeScrollbars" is written with small "b". +1 Thanks anyway!

Comment: This is more helpful answer

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish this with the method [setScrollbarFadingEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScrollbarFadingEnabled%28boolean%29) on the View object.

Comment: I don't know, what i'm doing wrong, but i don't see this method either for View or for ListView object.

Comment: You need to set your `targetSdkVersion` in your manifest to `5` or higher.

Comment: I get this message "The method setScrollbarFadingEnabled(boolean) is undefined for the type View"

Comment: @Joseph Earl And were there alternatives for SDKVersions < 5?

Comment: No, because the fading scrollbar behaviour wasn't present in previous versions so there was no need for an attribute to disable it! If your `minSdkVersion` is below `5` you'll have to use Reflection to make sure the scrollbar stays visible on newer devices - take a look at http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html

Comment: i tried to set targetSdkVersion 6 but i still get that message :(

Comment: ok, build target should be changed and probably it should be checked from app if targetSDKApi > 4

Comment: If you follow the link provided in the answer, you will notice that the API version it was introduced at is specified (in this case, 5).  Have you tried changing target and min to 5 and then rebuilding the app?

Comment: @Nicholas OMG ... they could write the API versions smaller so that nobody could find it. I tried setScrollbarFadingEnabled on my device with true and false, there are some differences, but scrollbar are still dissappearing :(

Comment: `Method showBars = View.class.getMethod("setScrollbarFadingEnabled", boolean.class);
showBars.invoke(answerList, false);`

this works